NodeJS Websockets with Traefiks
i do have a Angular App which uses Websockets (in dev environment, everything works, also for the WS stuff) together with Node JS. Now i do want to put all of this behind a traefiks, but i do get a 504, in case i want to use the websocket service. I have changed the URL also in "https://my-domain.de:8080", but none of these tries were successfull:
this.socket = io("https://backend.my-domain.de:8080"); 

backend is a subdomain, which is working for all HTTP pathes, that are available on my node JS express server. So if i call "https://backend.my-domain.de/getAllUsers" would work perfectly fine with this. However ontop of this server i create the WS:
(async () => {
try {
    const app = express();
    const API = await new APIconfig(`${__dirname}/config/APIconfig.json`).getConfig();
    mongoose.connect(API.MONGODB_PRODENVIROMENT_API);
    const serverInstance = server.createServer(app);
    fromEvent(serverInstance.listen(API.PORT, () => console.log(`Server is listening on 'http://localhost:${API.PORT}`)), 'listening')
        .pipe(
            tap(new CorsConfiguration(app)),
            tap(new httpRoutesConfiguration(app)),
            tap(new WebsocketServerConfiguration(serverInstance)),
        )
} catch (ex) {
    logger.error(ex);

})();
The websocket server looks like that:
module.exports = class WebsocketServerConfiguration {

// broadcast to all users. Check for client.connected=true property
socketConnections = [];

constructor(server) {
    this.io = socket(server, { cors: { origin: '*' } });
    this.socket = this.io.on('connection', (socket) => {return socket });
 //   this.eventController = new eventController();
    this.registerOnConnection();
}

}
So the port for the node js server (serverInstance on my example) listen to Port 8080.
Every call to this server uses a subdomain "backend" like this:
services:
   backend:
  image: node:latest
  container_name: nodejs-backend
  command: node /usr/src/app/index.js
  volumes:
     - ./dist:/usr/src/app
     - ./img:/usr/src/app/img
  networks:
     - default
     - web
  labels:
     - traefik.enable=true
     - traefik.http.routers.backend.rule=Host(`backend.my-domain.de`) 
     - traefik.http.routers.backend.tls=true
     - traefik.http.routers.backend.tls.certresolver=lets-encrypt
     - traefik.http.services.backend.loadbalancer.server.port=8080

networks:
web:
external: true
So this example works on prod for any regular API call, but not for WS. Can you give me a hint, how to solve this problem? The Traefiks logs were not shown any helpful information. Do i need to build up another server instance just for WS, which uses a different Port then the main backend? I do not know if both can run on 8080, which i did for development. Thanks guys

Share your full Traefik static and dynamic configuration, and docker-compose.yml if used.
